# Angular. Некорректно работает валидатор для поля проверки пароля

Tags: typescript, angular, пароль

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся. Написал кастомный валидатор для проверки пароля, но работает он не так как я задумал. Ожидал, что при вводе в поле Confirm password пароль будет невалиден, если пароли не совпадают. Но выходит, что поле Сonfirm password валидно при вводе абсолютно любого символа.

```
app.component.ts

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      //...
      password: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.pattern(/^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^#$_\-+!]*[#$_\-+!]).{5,}$/),
      ]),
      confirmPassword: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
      ]),
    }, {validators: this.passwordMatchValidator});
  }

  passwordMatchValidator(form: FormGroup) {
    return form.value.password === form.value.confirmPassword ? null : { mismatch: true};
  }
```

---

```
app.component.html
div class="container">
  <form class="auth-form"
        [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <h1>Registration new User</h1>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label>Password:
          <input class="form-input" type="password" name="password"
           formControlName="password"
    pattern="^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^#$_\-+!]*[#$_\-+!]).{5,}$">
       </label>
       <div *ngIf="form.get('password').invalid && form.get('password').touched"
           class="validation">
        <small *ngIf="form.get('password').errors.required">
          The password field is required. </small>
        <small *ngIf="form.get('password').errors.minlength">
          The password must be at least {{form.get('password').errors.minlength["requiredLength"]}} characters.
        </small>
        <br>
        <small *ngIf="form.get('password').errors.pattern">
          The password must include uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers, and one of symbols: '_' '!' '#' '+' '-' '$'
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-control">
      <label>Confirm password:
        <input class="form-input" type="password" name="confirmPassword"  formControlName="confirmPassword"></label>
      <div *ngIf="form.get('confirmPassword').invalid && form.get('confirmPassword').touched"
           class="validation">
        <small *ngIf="form.get('confirmPassword').errors.required">
          The Confirm Password field is required.
        </small>
        <small *ngIf="form.errors || form.get('confirmPassword').errors.mismatch">
          Password doesn't match.
        </small>

      </div>
    </div>

<button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

ссылка на stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvrnrf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: а почему оно должно быть не валидно? С контролом слинкован 1 валидатор required

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста новичку, первую неделю на ангуляре пишу. Т.е. когда указан этот валидатор  {validators: this.passwordMatchValidator}, он не распространяется на поле confirmPassword? Не понимаю тогда, как для confirmPassword должен выглядеть нормальный валидатор?

Comment: Если я добавляю те же валидаторы, что и в password - Validators.minLength(5) и Validators.pattern(/^...$/), всё равно могу в поле confirmPassword вписать любой другой пароль, и он считает его валидным, даже если они с password разные

Answer (score 0):

Я  решил сделать C реактивной формой Angular и как советуют с FormBuilder
        Вот код:

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  formReg: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService { this._createForm(); }

  private _createForm() {
    this.formReg = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z0-9]*')
      ]],
      password: [
        '',
        [ Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3),
          Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z0-9]*')
        ]
      ]
    });
  }
  get  _username() {return this.formReg.get('username'); }
  get  _password() {return this.formReg.get('password'); }

  ngOnInit() {...}
```

и мой html

```
<form [formGroup]="formReg" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">username </label>
      <input type="username" name="username" id="username" formControlName="username" class="form-control"
             aria-describedby="usernameHelp" placeholder="Enter username" required>
      <br><small id="usernameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">you username account</small>
      <div *ngIf="_username.invalid && (_username.dirty || _username.touched)" class="alert alert-danger"></div>
      <div *ngIf="_username.errors?.required">Обязательное поле</div>
      <div *ngIf="_username.errors?.minlength">Введите не менее 2 символов</div>
      <span *ngIf="_username.errors?.pattern">Неразрешенные символы</span>
 </div>
```

тоже самое и для password

Comment: Благодарю за помощь :)

Comment: рад помочь! если воспользовались и все работает можете проголосовать за мой ответ! я тут новичок  думаю мне не помешает. успехов